# Getting key value from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

trying to get key value returns null, but it returns all data in json format. Response added below as image

```
   $("#txtbox").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: "url.aspx/GetData",
                            data: "{'Prefix':'" + request.term + "'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                $.each(data, function (i, field) {
                                    var data = JSON.stringify(data);
                                    console.log(data.diagnosisdesc);
                                });

                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                alert("Error");
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 3
                });
```

[image: Json Output]

Comment: paste the response here

Comment: Your array is in `data.d` and you never call `response(arrayToDisplay)` with mapped array for the plugin to display

Comment: You need to add another each loop in the current loop.

Comment: @charlietfl I did that earlier: TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for '(length - 1)' in '[

Comment: Not clear how you generated that error. Should be `$.each(data.d, function(i, el){ console.log(el.diagnosisdesc)})`

Comment: response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                var data = JSON.stringify(data.d);
                                $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                                    console.log(key, value);
                                });
                            }));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the server has a object: `d`; the object is an array, so you need to loop thru the array, and then loop thru each one of the array values. Each array value will contain an object, so you can loop those objects with the jQuery function `$.each` if you like (to avoid using `hasOwnProperty` to filter the iterated object).

According to the jQuery UI plugin you need to pass an array to the `response` callback. Each value of the array must be an object containing two properties: `value` and `label`, so you will need to `map` the response from the server to create the array and pass it to the `response` callback. As documented in the plugin page, you also need to pass a value to the callback in case of error. In this case an empty array.

```
$("#txtbox").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "url.aspx/GetData",
                data: "{'Prefix':'" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(value) {
                        return {
                            label: value.diagnosisdesc,
                            value: value. diagnosisdesc + '//' + value.diagnosiscode
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    response([]);
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3
    });
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for '(length - 1)' in '[

Comment: @NiangMoore can you post the raw json?

Comment: [
  {
    "diagnosiscode": "A00",
    "diagnosisdesc": "Cholera"
  },
  {
    "diagnosiscode": "A000",
    "diagnosisdesc": "Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01 biovar cholerae"
  },
  {
    "diagnosiscode": "A001",
    "diagnosisdesc": "Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01 biovar el tor"
  }]

Comment: after passing the data as json, i can see the data in console but cannot access individual item (value.diagnosisdesc)


                            for (var x = 0, max = data.d.length; x < max; x = x + 1) {
                                // Loop thru each one of the object values
                                $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(data.d)[x], function (key, value) {
                                    console.log(key, value);
                                    console.log(value.diagnosisdesc);
                                });
                            }

Comment: @NiangMoore inside the `$.each` loop just use: `data.d[x].diagnosisdesc`. Or you can even skip that loop and call `data.d[x].diagnosisdesc` inside the for loop. Otherwise you will log the value many times as properties has the object.

Comment: it seems to be working with this code but it does not display the autocomplete, I can only see it on console
                            response($.map(jQuery.parseJSON(data.d), function (item) {
                                console.log(item.diagnosisdesc);
                                return {
                                    value: item.diagnosisdesc,
                                    label: item.diagnosisdesc + '//' + item.diagnosiscode
                                };
                            }));

Comment: @NiangMoore an which is the format you need to return?

Comment: @NiangMoore i edited my answer code to adjust it according to the autocomplete plugin documentation.